# Adding property to styled component fails in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a simple component that takes a `variant` and a `text` property. On my `styled-component` I have added the `as` property. TS will error with this property, without it it passes. I am rather confused why a property for a styled component would need me to define the props as I am not defining the prop definitions.

```js
import React, { FC } from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'

interface ITypography {
  variant?: string,
  text: string,
}

interface IStyledTypography {
  as: any
}

const Typography: FC<ITypography> = ({variant = 'div', text}) => {
  const StyledTypography = styled.div<IStyledTypography>`
    margin: 0;
  `
  return (
    <StyledTypography as={variant}>
      {text}
    </StyledTypography>
  )

}

export default Typography
```

## Error

```js
/var/www/SpaceSpot-UIComponents/src/components/shared/Typography/index.tsx
TypeScript error in /var/www/SpaceSpot-UIComponents/src/components/shared/Typography/index.tsx(15,23):
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: Pick<Pick<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>, "style" | "title" | ... 252 more ... | "onTransitionEndCapture"> & { ...; }, "style" | ... 254 more ... | "onTransitionEndCapture"> & Partial<...>, "style" | ... 254 more ... | "onTransitionEndCapture"> & { ...; } & { ...; }): ReactElement<...>', gave the following error.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: StyledComponentPropsWithAs<"symbol" | "object" | "div" | "text" | "a" | "abbr" | "address" | "area" | "article" | "aside" | "audio" | "b" | "base" | "bdi" | "bdo" | "big" | "blockquote" | "body" | "br" | "button" | ... 155 more ... | FunctionComponent<...>, any, {}, never>): ReactElement<...>', gave the following error.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"symbol" | "object" | "div" | "text" | "a" | "abbr" | "address" | "area" | "article" | "aside" | "audio" | "b" | "base" | "bdi" | "bdo" | "big" | "blockquote" | "body" | "br" | "button" | ... 156 more ... | undefined'.  TS2769

    13 |   `
    14 |   return (
  > 15 |     <StyledTypography as={variant}>
       |                       ^
    16 |       {text}
    17 |     </StyledTypography>
    18 |   )
```

[Edit]

I have kept playing and received this error too. Its a pickle for sure

```
import React, { FC } from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'

interface ITypography {
  variant?: keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements,
  text: string,
}
const Typography: FC<ITypography> = ({variant, text}) => {
  const StyledTypography = styled.div`
    margin: 0;
  `
  return (
    <StyledTypography as={variant ?? 'div'}>
      {text}
    </StyledTypography>
  )
}
export default Typography
```

## Error

`Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite.  TS2589`